# How to display user photo when user muted video instead of black screen on both local and remote? Agora Web Chat

Tags: javascript, agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng, agora, agora-implementation

I developed one to one video call with Agora Web but I want add image or icon on both remote and local screen instead of black screen when user muted video.

When the remote or local user muted the video it is showing black screen on both sides. I want remove black screen then add image or icon. By doing this users knows the user status like they are on mute or unmute.

Windows and Mac are two users calling each other:

[image: For better understand see the image]

Is there any way to add images or icon instead of black screen?